# Is there a way to track a tag?

Tags: support, tags, notifications

Some time ago I published a .Net library on Nuget, and lately it's been becoming more popular.  As such, I'd like to be able to track questions tagged with my library's name.  Is there a way to receive notifications (either through the SE app on my phone or through the website) when a new question is posted with my tag?

I have my tags set up as favorites, but without constantly checking, new questions could be posted without my knowledge.

If this is not a current feature, I think it would be a nice one to have.

Answer (score 7):

Go to the tag page and scroll all the way down to the bottom. There you'll find the tags RSS feed.

[image]

It has the form:

`https://stackoverflow.com/feeds/tag/[tagname]`

e.g. this is the one for the [apache](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/tagged/apache) tag:

> https://stackoverflow.com/feeds/tag/apache

It may not be the latest technology, but it should do the job.

Comment: Awesome!  It also looks like I can subscribe for email updates via a popup when I hover over the tag!

Comment: Also one  can use _favourite tags_ to get highlights